# How to jUnit test entity persistence with HRD w/o parent relationship

Tags: google-app-engine, junit

I'm struggling to find the right way to use jUnit to test the state of the datastore when using HRD.

My setup: App Engine 1.7.1, HRD set. I use of transactions on multiple entities. All is fine when running the app in dev mode in the browser.

My jUnit helper:
  protected final LocalServiceTestHelper helper = new LocalServiceTestHelper(new   LocalDatastoreServiceTestConfig().setDefaultHighRepJobPolicyUnappliedJobPercentage(50));

Problem: I persist few entities. They don't have a parent so I cannot consistently read the datastore to see if they are saved.

Question: How do I test they are saved in the datastore since some of the save ops won't be applied and I cannot access the parent to really check the datastore (because I don't use parent relationship)?

Note: HRD has to be used as I use XG transactions.

Is there a way to 'flush' pending operations?

Daniel

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Probably the best way to approach this is to define your own HighRepJobPolicy that applies every time, and register that for the tests you need it in.  Search for 'register your own' on this unittesting [docs](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests) page.

See this [discussion](https://groups.google.com/group/google-appengine-java/browse_thread/thread/24bbb6f4b4d93d5e/ce94b240d9df7347) also.

The example on the docs page shows how to write a policy that applies every other time, but you would instead write versions of those methods where all new and existing jobs do apply every time.

Comment: I can't get the example provide in the docs page (https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/localunittesting#Writing_HRD_Datastore_Tests) to commit all the jobs even w/ using a CustomHighRepJobPolicy that returns true for both shouldApplyNewJob() and shouldRollForwardExistingJob()

Answer (score 2):

You can consistently read entities if you get them by id or key, even if there is no parent.
Queries, however, will not return consistent results.

If you're setting the config to be eventually consistent, like you are, you should write your tests so that they can handle the eventually consistent results.

If you want to write your tests such that they expect fully consistent results, set the unapplied job percentage to 0 so it behaves in a fully consistent manner (doesn't reflect how it really runs though).

Comment: On HRD, non-ancestor queries are always eventually consistent: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/queries#Data_Consistency

Comment: That's what I said.  Fetching entities by keys (which is different from a query) will be strongly consistent.

Comment: @dragonx I think you are mistaken about fetching entities by key w/o parent being strongly consistent. Do you have a link to the doc about this?

Comment: See the first point of the last paragraph here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/python/datastore/overview#Datastore_Writes_and_Data_Visibility

Comment: @dragonx Sorry this is incorrect. We need to use the parent key to have strong consistency "To obtain strongly consistent query results, you need to use an ancestor query " according to Google doc here: https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/datastore/structuring_for_strong_consistency
line 5.

Comment: Fetching an entity by key is not a query.  BTW, an entity's parent is embedded in its key.

Comment: Also an entity without a parent is its own entity group, it'll be strongly consistent with itself.